# mongodb python Updating a subfield with a condition

Tags: python, mongodb

sitting on this for a while now. I have a database and a dictionary.
The structure of the db is the following:

```
    { 'label': 'Argiope',
  'uri': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Argiope_(spider)',
  'description': 'The genus Argiope includes rather large and spectacular spiders that often ...',
  'name': 'Argiope',
  'synonym': ["One", "Two"],
  'classification': {
                    'family': 'Orb-weaver spider',
                    'class': 'Arachnid',
                    'phylum': 'Arthropod',
                    'order': 'Spider',
                    'kingdom': 'Animal',
                    'genus': None
                    }
}
```

Now what i wanna do is, update the database by making a new entry in the classification field. the key is always the same "binomialAuthority" and the value, the value of my dict. But i only wanna update those datasets where label equals my key( so i just update the right ones)

i started with:

```
def update_db(data, db):
for key in data:
    db.arachnid.update({$set:{"classifaction".key:data[key]}})
pass
```

but that does not work and still is missing the condition.Anyone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your update should look something like:

```
db.arachnid.update({'label': 'binomialAuthority'}, {'$set': dict([('classification.' + key, value) for key, value in data.items()])}, multi=True)
```

*edit*

Reading you question again, maybe what you are looking for is:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    db.arachnid.update({'label': key}, {'$set': {'classification.' + key: value}})
```